# how to invoke message body reader for jaxrs

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a requirement that I need to send an xml from the restclient addon of firefox browser to the resource by adding that xml in the request body. For that I have written a message body reader implementation class and there I am converting that xml to java object. But I am not able to invoke that message body reader class. how to invoke that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't invoke a [MessageBodyReader](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html). You mark it as a [@Provider](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html) and ensure it's added to your JAX-RS application's [classes](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getClasses%28%29) or [singletons](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getSingletons%28%29). There are many ways to do that, some of which are dependent on which JAX-RS implementation you're using. The MessageBodyReader is invoked by the JAX-RS implementation when needed to convert an HTTP entity to a POJO based on media type.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have done the same thing that you have said. Can I send the xml by writing it in the request body directly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How else would you send XML other than in the request body?

Comment: I am using restclient add on for firefox. I am writing the xml in the reqbody and written the below code in msgbodyreader.

Comment: JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance(type);
Employee emp =(Employee)jaxb.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(entityStream);

Comment: my requirement is again i want to print the same xml as response.

Comment: Jersey comes with support for JAXB out of the box. There's no reason to write your own class to support it. And if you mean you want to be able to marshal an object back out to XML in the response, Jersey does that, too. Just follow the [plain vanilla example in the user guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e820).